# How to invoke class constructor from another file?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have 4 files water.h water.cpp ofApp.h ofApp.cpp

**water.h**

```
typedef struct _coordinate {
int x, y;}coordinate;

class water{
public:
    water(int num_of_line);
    ~water();

    void draw();
    void reset();

    int water_draw_flag;    // flag
    float local_r, local_g, local_b; // color of line


    coordinate* path;
    int num_of_path; };
```

**water.cpp**

```
#include "water.h"

water::water(int num_of_line)
{
   int num_of_path = num_of_line * 2 + 2;

if (!path) {
    path = (coordinate*)malloc(sizeof(coordinate)*(num_of_path+1));
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_path+1; i++) {
        path[i].x = path[i].y = -1;
    }
}

water_draw_flag = 0;
}
~~~~~
```

**ofApp.h**

```
#include "water.h"
#include <vector>

~~~~~

void initializeWaterLines(); 

vector<water> wa;
```

**ofApp.cpp**

```
#include "ofApp.h"

~~~~~
void ofApp::initializeWaterLines() {
int i = 0;
int num = 50;
int local_x, local_y;
water init(num_of_line);
wa.assign(num, init);

~~~~~}
```

I constructed a water class 'init' but the num_of_path and path within the water class are not initialized.
Why won't it initialize?

Comment: The definition `vector<water> wa;` in ofApp.h will result in a multiply defined symbol error from the linker if ofApp.h is included in more than one source file.  Variables should not be defined in header files.  You should declare `wa` with `extern vector<water> wa;` in the header, then define it with `vector<water> wa;` in ofApp.cpp.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
   int num_of_path = num_of_line * 2 + 2;
```

in the constructor creates a local variable, that overshadows the member variable. Get rid of the `int` and it will work. Even more preferable would be to use a member initialization list.

The check of `if(!path)` is undefined behavior, since there is no default initialization of `path`, it is just some random pointer, not `nullptr`. I would just remove the check, cause there is no possibility that path has an initialized value at this point.